# An error occurred during local report processing when loading report parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm trying to render a report using Reporting Services. The reportviewer (rdlc) doesn't open.
The error occurs when the parameters are being set:

```
An error occurred during local report processing. Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms An error occurred during local report processing.
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
  at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at AV.certificado.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\AV\DEV\V1.0.0\V1.0.0\AV\AV\Proposta.aspx.cs:line 297
```

The error happens at the second line:

```
rpvProposta.LocalReport.ReportPath = MapPath("certificados/rptProposta2.rdlc");
rpvProposta.LocalReport.SetParameters(lstRptParameter);
```

I've already checked and the report path is valid, and already verified permissions on IIS.
I can acces the XML of the report through the browser if I call it directly.

Comment: What exactly is lstRptParameter? It looks like your problem is originating from there. Have you checked that the parameters for the report are correct?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?